# PHP POSTGRESQL database connection

Tags: php, database

if I use this code to connect database it is showing nothing, if I give wrong database name also it is not showing error I'm using this code in ubuntu 16.04. path var/www/html

```
<?php
//dvdstoredbfunctions.php
// Global Variables
$host="localhost";
$port="";
$db_name="dvd_store";
$options="";
$tty="";
$db_user="dvd_user";
$db_password="";
$err_mesg;
$db_conn;
```

Comment: These are just a bunch of variables, you haven't establish any connection with your database, use either [pg_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `pg_connect` to connect to `postgresql`. If you want to use `PDO` see this [article](https://www.zentut.com/php-pdo/pdo-connecting-to-postgresql/), or [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). For `pg_connect`, I suggest you to do this:

```
$conn_string = "host=".$host." port=".$port." dbname=".$db_name." user=".$db_user." password=".$db_password;
$db_conn = pg_connect($conn_string);
```

If it's not connecting try to change `$port` to `5432`. `5432` is default port value of `postgresql`.